# Probabilty exam question

Tags: probability

I would like some help with what direction to take in this question.I find it difficult to decide what rule I need to use when I read a question.

Cars pass at an average rate of 1 every 10 seconds. Find the probability that
between 4 and 6 cars pass in the next minute.

Comment: I think you need more information than what is given to work out this probability.

Comment: To answer this question you need to know the distribution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. This is actually the full question but my lecturer likes to be difficult so its possible that assumptions need to be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When counting events that are the conjunction of a large number of independent and individually rare events (how often does a *specific* car in the world pass by?), one typically uses the Poisson distribution.  (It is true, as the commenters suggest, that this is not certain, but given what is in the problem, if you must make a choice, it is the most reasonable one.)  The rate here is $\lambda = 6$/minute.  The probability that $k$ cars pass by, given a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$ and time interval $t$, is given by

$$
P(k) = \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda t}
$$

What you need to do is to calculate $P(4), P(5), P(6)$, and add those all together; that will be the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much that's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the events are random and the average rate per minute is constant, and provided the events are independent, effectively instantaneous and not simultaneous, then use the Poisson distribution. The required parameter value is 6 since you expect on average one every ten seconds. The clue is in the words "average rate" for every unit of time.